# Javascript: How to get the reference to child window object after refreshing parent window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a functionality of opening up a pop up window when a home page(parent window) is visited. I have a setInterval function which checks if the pop up window is closed or not. If closed it reopens the pop up window.

But when the parent window is refreshed and the pop up window (child window) is closed. It does not reopen as the window object becomes null and if(Window !== null && Window.closed)  condition is not true.
Any help with how to get the pop up window to relaunch when closed after refreshing the home page or how to get the reference of the child window object after parent window refresh.

```
var Window = null;

    var WindowLauncher = function() {
        //Timer to check if window is closed
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if(Window !== null && Window.closed) {
                try{
                    alert("DO NOT CLOSE WINDOW");
                    this.launchWindow();
                } catch (e) {
                    log.error('Window is closed but we are unable to open the login popup. %s', e.getMessage()).withException(e);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    };

WindowLauncher.prototype.init = function() {
        // has a event subscription code. When a timeout event triggers it calls the launchWindow()
    };


WindowLauncher.prototype.launchWindow = function () {
        var width = 360;
        var height = 520;
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
        var top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
        Window = window.open(URL, true, 'width=' + width + ',height=' + height + ',menubar=no,status=no,toolbar=no,left=' + left + ',top=' + top);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference the child window object after the parent window is refreshed. The child window object has to be created using a window name.

```
window_obj = window.open(URL, "window-name", .... (window features) )
```

As on refreshing the parent window, window_obj reference is lost and it becomes null. So fetch the window reference using the window name.

```
if(window_obj.location.href === "about:blank"){
    window_obj.close() // closes the empty pop up window
    window_obj = window.open(URL, "window-name", .... (window features) ) // opens a new window
}
else{
   window_obj.focus() // if the window is already open it just puts focus on that window 
}
```

When a child pop up window is closed after the parent window is refreshed. We can get the child pop up window's reference.